# React Native Unexpected Token on If statment

Tags: react-native

I'm new to this, so it's likely this is something easy, but I cannot understand it.
Here is my simple example:

```
export default class WhyScreen extends React.Component { 

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.index = false;
 }


 if (this.index){
    console.log('ok');
 }

render() {    
  return (
      <View style={styles.parag}>

      </View>

      );
}
```

If take out the if statement, I get no error.  But once I put in the if statement I get an Unexpected Token error on the line with If statement.  In fact, it does make any different if I'm testing a condition, or simply testing 1===1, I still get an error.  Obviously, I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhyScreen is a class, so you would need to create a method for that code to work. Or if you want it to run upon creation you can put it in the constructor.

```
export default class WhyScreen extends React.Component { 

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.index = false;
  if (this.index) {
    console.log('ok');
  }
 }

 testIndex = () => {
   if (this.index){
      console.log('ok');
   }
 }

render() {    
  return (
      <View style={styles.parag}>

      </View>

      );
}
```

Comment: Thanks..that's makes a lot of sense.